# TCP winsock File uploading using C++ TransmitFile and overlapped I/O

Tags: c++, winsock

I am writing an application responsible for uploading files to server, in C++ Winsock, i wrote it successfully using the multithreading technique and it works fine with no errors. But when i want to make use of Overlapped I/O techniques, i faced a problem that not all the file is received by the server.
  I will post code sections that are related to sending and receiving files.

```
int iRecv = WSARecv(AcceptSocket, &DataBuf, 1, &RecvBytes, &Flags, &AcceptOverlapped, NULL);
int iBytesReceived = 0;
while(true)
{   
    printf("error =%d\r",WSAGetLastError());
    // Step 7:
    //  Determine the status of the overlapped
    //  request
    WSAGetOverlappedResult(AcceptSocket, &AcceptOverlapped, &BytesTransferred, FALSE, &Flags);

    // Step 5:
    //  Wait for the overlapped I/O call to complete
    Index = WSAWaitForMultipleEvents(EventTotal, EventArray, FALSE, WSA_INFINITE, FALSE);

    // Index should be 0 because we 
    // have only one event handle in EventArray
    // Step 6:
    //  Reset the signaled event
    WSAResetEvent(EventArray[Index - WSA_WAIT_EVENT_0]);
    if( iRecv>=0)
    {    
        iBytesReceived += RecvBytes;
        fwrite(DataBuf.buf,sizeof(char), RecvBytes,flUploadedFile);
    }
    if (lReceivedBytes>=iFilesize)  break;

    Flags = 0;
    ZeroMemory(&AcceptOverlapped, sizeof(WSAOVERLAPPED));
    AcceptOverlapped.hEvent = EventArray[Index - WSA_WAIT_EVENT_0];

    DataBuf.len = DATA_BUFSIZE;//1024
    DataBuf.buf = buffer;

    iRecv=WSARecv(AcceptSocket, &DataBuf, 1, &RecvBytes, &Flags, &AcceptOverlapped, NULL);
}
```

I have to mention that server is receiving the filename and file size correctly.

Client-side

```
void UploadFile(....)
{
    .
    .
    .   
hFile = CreateFile(fp,GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL,   OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN,NULL);
bTrans= TransmitFile(connectedSocket,hFile,0,0,NULL,NULL,0) ;     
    .
    .
}
```

Does their exist any error in my code? Any suggestion or help? i am stuck.

Comment: MSDN, WSARecv, lpNumberOfBytesRecvd [out]:  'A pointer to the number, in bytes, of data received by this call if the receive operation completes immediately'.  If it does not, (and it probably won't), the bytes recieved is returned by the call to WSAGetOverlappedResult().  Calling WGOR() before the wait on the hEvent handle has returned and not checking the WGOR returned value for error, is not a good idea.  What did you see for the various values, at various stages, when you ran this code under your debugger?

Comment: Also, this sort of stuff is much easier with either completion routines or full IOCP.  The hEvent wait mechanism is a PITA to manage.

Answer (score 1):

In seems that the first `WSARecv()` returns immediate with the first portion of data (file name and size). Then the code blocks because you want to get the overlapped result before the OS signals that the result is available (by setting the event handle).

Perhaps you should use a completion routine when using overlapped I/O, this will make it more easy.